# Can I set variable value with function result "inline" in Swift?

Tags: swift

Sorry if it is a stupid question but I think that may be possible do something like that:

```
lblTitle.text = {
            switch tag {
            case 0:
                return "title0"
            default:
                return "DefaultTitle"
            }
        }->String
```

I know that this is incorrect but, there is any way to do that?

I've been looking for a long time in the Apple documentation and on the Internet and I find nothing.

Comment: As a side note. You really should avoid using the `tag` property of `UIView`. It is really, very bad practise to use this. There is always a better way of doing things without using `tag`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
lblTitle.text = {
            switch tag {
            case 0:
                return "title0"
            default:
                return "DefaultTitle"
            }
        }()
```

Just wanted to add to this.

You can also create variables this way but you will need to add type information like this...

```
// If you don't provide type then the closure is ambiguous
let someLabel: UILabel = {
    let l = UILabel()
    l.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    l.textColor = .red
    l.text = "Hello, world!"
    return l
}()
```

Comment: YES!  IT IS

I had tried everything except this

Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 2):

you can code like this if you have only two result for tag variable.

```
lblTitle.text = tag == 0 ? "title0" : "DefaultTitle"
```